# How to generate random string in Symfony 2.8?

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate random string in my services on Symfony 2.8. However I could not do. I was looking on internet. There are some deprecated solution. I need the most updated solution about that problem.

Comment: Define "random"

Comment: Can you be more specific about the string you're trying to generate? A certain length? Containing a specific set of characters?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I would like to generate alphanumeric string with dynamic length

Comment: Did you check this page? https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/secure_tools.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function generateRandomString($length = 16, $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    {
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
```

I solved with this. no error no dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) if you don't have restriction about length